# Data migration from MongoDB to Teradata

Tags: mongodb, teradata, mongodb-java

We are working towards migrating data from MongoDB to Teradata (DW).

We feel that transformations on the data will be necessary.

Could you please help me answer the below questions which will guide us on developing a solution for migration :

1. Which would be the best and efficient format to export data from MongoDB to load into Teradata(DW) considering transformations involved ? (CSV/JSON/Others)

Transformations could include omission of line(s) from the exported file, omission of fields, aggregation(sum/count) across fields etc.

2. If developing a framework for ETL, will Java be a good choice ?
3. We noticed that ‘\n’ [newline character] is also part of some records. Hence, in the csv we are seeing some blank lines in between.

Do we need to be concerned of the right line delimiter ? Or can the export format help us in this regard ?

4. We are seeing some records getting truncated because the length of the record exceeds 1024 characters.

We get the ‘Line too long’ message in VI editor. We don’t have an alternate editor in our system. Is there a way around to handle line truncation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV is not particularly well-specified - there are several variants of it in the wild with slightly different escaping behaviors. I almost always prefer anything-but-csv.

1. JSON
2. Yes
3. This is not a question, but ok.
4. Don't edit the data with vi, this is purely a limitation of the editor and not the export format. Do transformations programmatically